# Factory boy does not create row in db

Tags: python, pytest, factory-boy

Cant understand why UserFactory() or UserFactrory.create() does not actually create a record. It just creates User object in memory, even without pk.

```
class UserFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker("first_name")
    phone_number = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.phone_number())
    password = factory.Faker("password")

    class Meta:
        __Session = scoped_session(session_factory=get_async_session())
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = __Session
```

```
def test_user_signup(api_client: TestClient, test_db):
    user = UserFactory()  # should create record in dd according to Factory boy docs
    r = api_client.post("/api/v1/auth/signup",
                        json={"name": user.name, "phone_number": user.phone_number, "password": user.password})
    assert r.status_code == 400
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not calling `test_db.add(user)`.  Where did you read that it would be committed automatically?

Comment: @TimRoberts https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#sqlalchemy

Comment: OK, I see.  And where are the field values for your new User record supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1):

The issue likely stems from your `session` usage.

I guess `get_async_session` returns a brand new session, which isn't the same as the session you're using in your API.

Two possible options:

- Set `sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"` in your `class Meta`;
- Configure your test setup to use the same `session` in your factories and in the application under test.